# "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" mobile device

Tags: php, angular, symfony, nelmiocorsbundle

I have an issue with CORS on my Angular 6/Symfony 4 project.
This project have login/register module. I'm using FOSUserBundle and set enabled to false by default. Then, I send an email with a confirmation link (https://subdomain.example.com/confirm-email/CONFIRMATION_TOKEN) to verify that it's not a bot.
The link redirects to a special page in Angular who PUT the user account to enable it.
The thing is, everything works fine on laptop with any browser but when I want to do it with my phone, nothing append. I've tried to alert the error message and I got this :

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{}, "lazyUpdate":null,"headers": {}},"status":0,"statusText":"UnknownError","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

So, I've got some researches and I found out that it is a CORS problem, some topics said it's Angular, some others said that the server has a wrong configuration. I've read lots of articles on CORS and I actually didn't any progress to resolve this issue.

Here are some samples :

**Symfony, .env**

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https://subdomain.example.com$
```

**Symfony, nelmio_cors.yaml**

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

**Angular, login.service.ts**

```
async confirmUser(confirmToken: string): Promise<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        })
    };

    return await this.http.post(`${this.url}/user/${confirmToken}`, httpOptions).toPromise();
}
```

**Angular, confirm-user.component.ts**

```
async confirmUser() {
    try {
      await this.loginService.confirmUser(this.confirmToken);
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
      }, 1000);
    } catch (error) {
      swal({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: error.statusText,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
        timer: 2000
      });
    }
}
```

I really don't know what is the problem and why it's not working on mobile device while it's works perfectly with a laptop. I'm using Browserstack to test on multiple devices (iOS, Android). Same with my mobile (iOS12) with Safari and Chrome.

FYI, those two project are on the same server but with two different url.
Ex : subdomain.example.com and subdomain-api.example.com

If someone has ever encountered this and has a solution, please be my guest.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks to [sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) for removing my cors tag, while checking your profile I saw one of your [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141) and tried "How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems" method. And it works for the OPTIONS request but not for the POST (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcwu.jpg). And for this I have maybe a solution : My CTO blocked by IP the access to the API. We only allow example.com, subdomain.example.com and IP's from our company. So, I guess we should allow https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ IP but is there another alternative ?

Comment: The screenshot at https://imgur.com/0WkeYlQ shows the response is a 403. If the server’s responding with at 403 then there’s no way to work around that from the client side. If the server is blocking based on IP address then I guess your only option would be make the request on the backend running on a server with an IP address that’s allowed instead of blocked, if you have access to such

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to such configuration and my CTO is Out Of Office today so I can't fix it until monday. I'll keep you in touch. Thanks for your reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* this is a CORS issue - that would normally show up as a CORS-specific error message - something like "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header found".

Can you supply a full set of request *and* response headers for a failing request?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time.
Here is the requested set : https://imgur.com/a/JKRHS4O